# Simple text rendering on iPhone (NOT UIWebView)

Tags: iphone, text, render

Is there any SIMPLE way of rendering formatted text (from a char* buffer) to the display...?
And I mean, simple.... In C or C++ or even Java, on nearly any platform, including embedded, you can get a pointer to a framebuffer or display and render simple text or pixels with 2 or 3, 5 max lines of code....

I have been looking in across the web (and in iphone development books) but I have yet to see
any rendering of text to the display, without going through a whole host of "UI~something~Views" to put a couple lines of text on the screen...

Please tell me I am wrong, and there is a very simple way to render text, nothing fancy, just two or three lines of plain old ascii text, no bells and whistles, just black and white text....

Something like: 
void my_callback()
{
  Global_Pointer_to_screen(x,y,data);
}

Thank you!

Comment: I'm very curious how you managed to write program to render text to a frame buffer in 5 lines of code in C++/C/Java.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is it just for debug purpose or really some output to the iPhone app user?

Comment: "I'm very curious how you managed to write program to render text to a frame buffer in 5 lines of code in C++/C/Java."

Easy It"s called a framebuffer... Or if you"ve you"ve ever accessed hardware level graphics function... or ever ported freetype or libjpg/png, ect... You would find 100 odd ways to render pixels (or text) lower-level... Maybe I mistated a bit grouping "Java" in among C/C++ for screen pixel / bit manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [**UILabel**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) to render text. Nothing fancy:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithCString:myCString encoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
UILabel myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width/2), 0.0, 100.0, 50.0) ];
[self addSubview:myLabel];
myLabel.text = myString;
```

The above code really isn't that difficult to implement. I'm not really sure why you want to write directly to the display buffer. I'm not even sure you can do this at all. I'm pretty sure Apple don't provide a way to do this unless you are using OpenGL. Even then you can't get a pointer to the display and write to the graphics memory using a pointer as far as i know.

I'd strongly advise you to learn `UIViews` and to do it the proper way.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the question suggesting he doesn't want to use IB; it's possible he doesn't know much about it.

Comment: Great thank you "Brock Woolf"!

Despise isn't a strong enough a word for how I feel about cocoa, xcode & object-c...

I am use to vim & a Makefile. Neither if of which can be used for this Xcode BS... It took me an hour to get rid of a warning xcode was giving, because something had been moved in the project directory, before I gave up looking at the "project settings UI" and manually grepp'd for the damn thing and physically removed it from the file, by force... what a framework...

Answer (score 0):

You can use UILabels in drawRect: to draw a formatted string into a specific location, you just set the frame and manually call drawRect on the label.

Or you can also use Quart2D to render text to the display as well:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html

As you can see you have a variety of methods to configure the text you are drawing.

But mostly people simple make UILabels in InterfaceBuilder and then they go on the screen.

In iOS4.x+, you have NSAttributedString that you can use to do real formatted text.  But it's pretty complex.